# How to increase maximum execution time in dompdf

Tags: php, dompdf

I am getting this error:

> Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in dompdf/includes/style.cls.php

and I have tried this solution:

```
ini_set ('max_execution_time',0);
ini_set('max_execution_time',120);
```

but it is still giving me the above error.

Comment: Are you running an old PHP version in `safe mode`?

Comment: when i use $dompdf->set_paper("A3","landscape"); the error does not come but one column disappears from the pdf so i had used 'a4',landscape but by using that the maximum execution time error occurs.

Comment: This question doesn't really concern dompdf directly. It's a PHP question. Depending on your hosting environment you may or may not be able to modify the max_execution_time. Can you provide more details on your host?

Comment: Changing the page dimensions does seem to be a genuine issue and you might want to ask a new question with details about your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Or:

```
set_time_limit(120);
```